# crossdomainpolicy and subfolders

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3, flash, silverlight, cross-domain

After making a request to server in my flash app I get the following error

> Error #2044: Unhandled SecurityErrorEvent:. text=Error #2048: Security
>   sandbox violation:
>   http://domain.com/subfolder/app.swf cannot load
>   data from https://domain.com/cgi-bin/app.n

In `clientaccesspolicy.xml` I'm having the following

```
<access-policy>
    <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
            <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
                <domain uri="*"/>
            </allow-from>
            <grant-to>
                <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
            </grant-to>
        </policy>
    </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

In `crossdomain.xml` I'm having

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

How should I modify the above file so that request will be ok?

Comment: Where is your crossdomain.xml located? It has to be in the root of the server folder for flash to be able to see it. If you don't want anything visible on the root you can setup your server to use another folder as the "root". For example for Tomcat you can do it like so:
in the server.xml you'll need `<Context docBase="your folder here">   </Context>` and you whatever folder you use as the docBase will be considered the "root" for flash (and other connections) to go looking for things. This would go within the `<Host>` brackets.

Comment: Additionally, since I can see `https`, make sure your server is actually setup to handle secure connections. Or you could handle that on the load balancer if you use one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Security sandbox violation cannot load data from box.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981702/security-sandbox-violation-cannot-load-data-from-box-net)